# Animating three js mesh in the canvas to the mapbox map

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

I created floating spheres in three js canvas.
I want to animate this floating spheres moving toward
the surface of mapbox 3d map tile.

I understand that
it's possible to create three Mesh within mapbox customlayer and
I know how to make three mesh using three.js canvas only.

However I can't think of way to animate meshes in three js space to mapbox map.(transitioning)

How do I achieve this?

The prototype I made is in the following link.
https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/QWpQZXv?editors=1011

In this demo the spheres are moving down to the plane.(this plane has to be mapbox map eventually)

-Summary-

1.I want to replace the map in the prototype to the mapbox map if it's possible.
2.I want to make a transition which moves floating spheres to the the mapbox map with corresponding coordinates on the map like the prototype.

(For example, [40.7128, -74.0060] if the sphere is supposed to be at New York City)
I can do that within custom layer of mapbox by doing

```
mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
    // type in coordinate informatino of model
    [148.9825, -35.39847],

    // height of model, normally 0 cause it will stand on the surface. if I wanna try to lift it up i can increase it
    // lets test this altitude later.
    modelAltitude
);
```

but I can't get out of this custom layer and make transition between only three js canvas to the mapbox custom layer.

Comment: Have you tried [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox)? That would abstract you from mapbox and layers an allow you to animate, rotate and translate any 3D object or model

Comment: @jscastro I just checked threebox and it seems like a library that shortens customization of 'customlayer' of mapbox.

Comment: It is, and also adds animations and simplification of Threejs capabilities for objects. Check out the gifs on some of the demos to see how easy it is to animate a 3D object in any part of the map

Comment: @jscastro thank you. I wonder if it's possible to make the background map invisible

Comment: Yes you only need an empty style file for mapbox if you only need the geopositioning part. Indeed if you don’t need style then you can even run it offline